# R - is there a way to create a nested %dopar% foreach loop?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, multicore, parallel-foreach

I am working with daily series of satellite images on a workstation with 64 cores.

For each image, I perform some algebra operations over all pixels using a `foreach` loop. Some testing revealed that the optimal number of cores for this `foreach` loop is 20.

This is roughly what I am doing now:

```
for (i in length(number_of_daily_images){

  # perform some pre-processing on each image

  # register cluster to loop over pixels
  registerDoParallel(20)

  out <- foreach(j=1:length(number_of_pixels_in_each_image)) %dopar% {

    # perform some calculations

  } # end inner loop
} # end outer loop
```

I only have to load the satellite image once, so there is very little I/O processing involved in this code. So there is definitely room for speeding up this code even further. Since I am only using one third of the cores available on the computer, I would like to run three days simultaneously to save some precious time in my workflow.

Therefore, I was thinking about also parallelizing my outer loop. It would be something like this:

```
# register cluster to loop over images
registerDoParallel(3)

out2 <- foreach (i = length(number_of_daily_images) %dopar% {

  # perform some pre-processing on each image

  # register cluster to loop over pixels
  registerDoParallel(20)

  out1 <- foreach(j = 1:length(number_of_pixels_in_each_image)) %dopar% {

    # perform some calculations

  } # end inner loop
} # end outer loop
```

However, when I run this code I get an error saying that one of the variables involved in the processing within the inner loop does not exist. But it works fine with a "regular" outter `for` loop.

Therefore, my question is: can I use two nested `%dopar%` loops in foreach like I was planning? If not, is there any other alternative to also parallelize my outer loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foreach maintainer here.

Use the `%:%` operator:

```r
registerDoParallel(60)

out2 <- foreach(i = 1:length(number_of_daily_images)) %:% 
  foreach(j = 1:length(number_of_pixels_in_each_image)) %dopar% {

    # perform some calculations
    something(i, j)

  }
```