# R - How to parallelize a for loop that contains a for loop which itself contains a foreach %dopar% loop?

Tags: r, foreach, nested, doparallel

I'm carrying out several independent (random) experiments on an igraph graph. I'd like to run them in parallel.

An experiment has several iterations (a for loop), and each iteration consists of a certain number of parallelized tasks (foreach, %dopar%). The results of all iterations (and thus the results of the experiment) are stored in a list. This concludes the experiment.

I've tried using the %:% operator along with %dopar%, as per [R - is there a way to create a nested %dopar% foreach loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61871638/r-is-there-a-way-to-create-a-nested-dopar-foreach-loop) and https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/nested.html. But my situation is different because there is a for loop (over iterations) separating the outer loop (over experiments) and the inner foreach %dopar% loop; therefore I don't know what to do.

My code looks like this:

```
library(igraph)

nb_trials <- 15
nb_iterations <- 60
nb_tasks <- 10
K <- 0.05

n.cores <- parallel::detectCores() - 1
my.cluster <- parallel::makeCluster(
  n.cores,
  type = "PSOCK"
)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl = my.cluster)

# Utility function for combining foreach outputs
comb <- function(x, ...) {
  lapply(seq_along(x),
         function(i) c(x[[i]], lapply(list(...), function(y) y[[i]])))
}

results_per_trial <- vector("list", nb_trials)

for (trial in 1:nb_trials) {
  initial_graph <- make_empty_graph()
  initial_graph <- initial_graph + vertices(name = c("A", "B", "C", "D"))
  initial_graph <- initial_graph + edges(c("A", "B", "A", "C", "A", "D"), attr1 = c(0, 0, 0), attr2 = c(0, 0, 0))
  results_per_iteration <- vector("list", nb_iterations)
  
  for (iter in 1:nb_iterations) {
    performance <- foreach(task = 1:nb_tasks, .combine = "comb", .packages = "igraph", .multicombine = TRUE, .init=list(list(), list())) %dopar% {
      current_graph <- initial_graph
      edge_attr(current_graph, "attr1", sample(3, 1)) <- rnorm(1)
      edge_attr(current_graph, "attr2", sample(3, 1)) <- runif(1)
      
      list(E(current_graph)$attr1, E(current_graph)$attr2)
      
    }
    edge_attr(initial_graph, "attr1") <- (1 - K)*E(initial_graph)$attr1 + Reduce('+', performance[[1]])
    edge_attr(initial_graph, "attr2") <- (1 - K)*E(initial_graph)$attr2 + Reduce('+', performance[[2]])
    results_per_iteration[[iter]] <- performance
    
  }
  
  results_per_trial[[trial]] <- results_per_iteration
  
}

}
```

I'd like to replace the "for (trial in 1:nb_trials)" loop by a foreach %dopar% one. Is this possible?

Comment: I think that one of the loops must be unparallelized. It is supposed that every step in a parallel loop will run in one core (or thread) of your PC, so it has no sense subdividing a multi-core process within that core (or thread).

Comment: @WenchengLau-Medrano: the question to which I referred (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61871638/r-is-there-a-way-to-create-a-nested-dopar-foreach-loop) describes almost the same situation (parallelizing a parallel loop). According to the answer it received, there is indeed a way of achieving this (via the nesting operator %:%). The difference between this case and mine is that the parallel loop (the inner loop) is itself inside a (normal) for loop.